# Unable to access sys_call_table

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I managed to find address of the **sys_call_table** by looking into **/proc/kallsyms**. I have the following code:

```
void **sys_call_table;

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

void Java_com_example_testlib_LibLoader_test() {
    sys_call_table = (void *) 0xc023cd28;
    LOGD("backup original sys_open %p", sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
}
```

The problem is that the code causes `Fatal Signal Exeption` why trying to get the **sys_call_table entry** `sys_call_table[__NR_open]`
I tried to get entry 0, 1, 2, ... as well.

Comment: You cannot modify the kernel from a user mode program!  Not only would this break the whole security and organization concept of kernel vs. user space, the addressing schemes often are not the same, requiring addresses to be translated.

Comment: But how the OS protects its memory from user space programs? I am very interested in the mechanism.

Comment: It does so by using hardware features of the processor and memory management unit - at a simple level, there may be a "kernel mode bit" in the processor flags.  Except of course on processors which lack this; if a multiuser OS is ported to one of these it may only pretend to have such mechanisms, with no actual enforcement against misbehaved programs.  Or code can be run in a virtual machine which enforces the rules when deciding to execute something or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is like Crhis said **"You cannot modify the kernel from a user mode program!"**

I compiled it as a LKM and loaded it using `insmod` command and it worked

**PS**: I have also found that only LKM modules can read `/proc/kallsyms`. User space programs are no longer to do so due to a kernel patch in Android 4.1. `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` is introduced to avoid leaking kernel addresses.

So now in order for userspace programs to see the kallsym address, we can either set kptr_restrict to either 0 or 1.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

Info can be found here:
https://blog.duosecurity.com/2012/07/exploit-mitigations-in-android-jelly-bean-4-1/

And here: http://insitusec.blogspot.sg/2013/01/kallsyms-on-android.html